# Dimensions of a Double Slit Diffraction Grating

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffraction

[image]

The first minima of the sinc function of a double slit diffraction grating can be found at $\theta = \pm 0.1^\circ$. For incident light at $\lambda = 400nm$ I am trying to find the dimensions $a$ and $b$ where $a$ is the spacing between slits and $b$ is the width of the slits. I know that the intensity pattern can be given by:

$$I = 4 I_0 \cos^2(\alpha) \frac {\sin^2(\beta)} {\beta^2}$$

Where
$$\alpha = k \frac a 2 \sin(\theta)$$
$$\beta = k\frac b 2 \sin(\theta) $$
$$k = \frac {2\pi}{\lambda}$$

Knowing that the minima at $\theta = \pm 0.1^\circ$ must correspond to $\beta = \pm \pi$ I find $b$ to be:
$$b = \frac {\lambda}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac {400\times10^{-9}}{\sin(0.1)} = 0.229mm $$
Now is the part I'm a bit stuck on. I thought I could assume that the first minimum of the $\cos^2(\alpha)$ function ($\alpha = \frac \pi 2$) would coincide with the first minimum of the $\sin(\beta)$ function. However when I try this I get:
$$k \frac a 2 \sin(\theta) = \frac \pi 2$$
$$\frac a \lambda \sin(\theta)= \frac 1 2$$
$$a = \frac {\lambda}{2\sin(\theta)}$$

Which would mean that the spacing between the slits is smaller than the width of the slits themselves and that doesn't really make sense. I guess there's something wrong with how I've understood the positioning of minima and maxima works in diffraction so I'd appreciate it if someone could set me right.

Comment: Are you sure b is the slit width and not their periodicity (that would be slit width + spacing between the slits)?

Comment: It should be, according to my notes anyway. I'll try to find a diagram that matches the derivation we did. EDIT: Added the diagram

Comment: exactly. Here a is the periodicity of the slits, not the spacing. I suppose b=w (width) in your derivation.

Comment: Yes @sleepy thats right we used $b$ instead of $w$ during the derivation. That would still mean there is something wrong though wouldn't it? If $a$ is the periodicity then it should be larger than $b = w$ right?

Comment: ok. I do not question your starting formula; it looks reasonable to me, but my memory is not perfect; anyway, I assume it is correct. Then, you find minima by setting either $\sin\beta=0$ or $\cos\alpha=0$. I don't see a reason why these minima (angles) should coincide; it is enough that one of the factors $=0$ for the entire intensity to be $=0$. I guess you could just figure $a$ so that the position of the first minimum is at 0.1 deg, and find a range of $b$-s so that it is really 1st minima, and $b<a$. 
Also, your $\sin(\beta)=±\pi$ after "Knowing that..." should be $\beta=±\pi$.